# How to use useState with Server Component in App Router?

Tags: react-hooks, next.js13, app-router

I'm trying to transition project to Next.js 13 App Router. I have a footer component, which needs to be SSR.

Quick example:

```
const Footer = () => {
  const [showSubmenu, setShowSubmenu] = useState(false);

  return(<footer>
    <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li onClick={(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      setShowSubmenu(true);
    }}>Item 3</li>
    </ul>

    {showSubmenu && (
      <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
        <li>Subitem 3</li>
        <li>Subitem 4</li>
      </ul>)
    }
  </footer>)
}
```

I need to have `useState` to conditionally render submenu chunk based on user interaction, but I need footer to be server side rendered. How to achieve it?

Comment: You can move the onClick list to another component and then use your footer as server component and providing data to it by props. You cannot make it whole a server component.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `useState` in an SSR.

You could wrap the SSR, in a `layout.js` component.

So that you can use the `useState` functionality for the footer while having the other part of the component as a SSR.